# The ordinary generating function for the square-free kernel: reference request about singularities and its phase plot

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, singularity

Let $n\geq 1$ an integer, in this post I denote the product of distinct prime numbers dividing dividing $n$ as $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p,$$
is the famous arithmetic function that appears in the abc conjecture.
See it you want the Wikipedia [*Radical of an integer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)

**Claim.** It's easy to prove that the ordinary generating function
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{rad}(n)z^n\tag{1}$$

for the square-free kernel or radica of $n$ has radius de convergence $1$.

*Proof.* It's obvious the inequality $1\leq \operatorname{rad}(n)\leq n$ thus $1\leq (\operatorname{rad}(n))^{1/n}\leq n^{1/n}$, and from here squeeze theorem implies $(\operatorname{rad}(n))^{1/n}\to 1$. And the Cauchy–Hadamard theorem that $R=1$.$\square$

> **Question 1.** I'm curious about what standard claims/questions, if any, can be stated about the singularities of a the generating function $f(z)$ over $|z|=1$. That is, imagine that we want to study the singularities of $f(z)$ over $|z|=1$, what questions can be studied? **Many thanks.**

Thus I'm asking what standard questions should can be studied being those potentially interesting. Aren't required deduction, only are required some details about what topics/issues can be studied about the set of singularities of $f(z)$ on the set of complex numbers $|z|=1$. If you know it, or more advanced questions from the literature refer it answering this Question 1 as a reference request, and I try to find and read the theory about previous generating function and its singularities from the literature.

I wondered previous and next question searching information about the generating function of the greatest prime factor (that is a different arithmetic function) 
 in Internet that I found [1].

> **Question 2 (Optional).** I would like to know* the *phase plot* for previous ordinary generating function $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{rad}(n)z^n$$ in the same spirit that is showed in the first plot of the section Greatest Prime Factor from Linas' Mathematical Art Gallery [1]. Can you provide us, or do you know it from the literature, the phase plot for $(1)$ over $|z|\leq 1$? **Many thanks.**

I would like to see the plot (feel free if you want to add some mathematical details about how calculate it) with the purpose to know it.

### References:

[1] *Greatest Prime Factor*, from Linas' Mathematical Art Gallery, home page of Lina Vepstas (2016).

Comment: Sorry, my comment may not work, I deleted it.

Comment: Many thanks any case for you attention and help @i707107